# Do I need to use Connection Retry for my SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I know that if you use SQL Azure cloud database you need to implement SQL Azure Connection Retry.
However, for SQL Server 2008 on Azure Virtual Machine, do I need to implement this method to retry connect
database server from web application.

My web application is hosted on AWS.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

When you use Windows Azure Virtual Machines and you take care of software installed on it (inc. SQL Server whatever version), you have to proceed as normally on a local ritualized environment. Meaning that you don't necessarily have to implement retry logic.

Comment: Thank you so much for fast reply. However I forgot to tell that my web application is hosted on AWS.

Comment: It doesn't matter where your application is hosted. Once you are in control/responsible of maintaining SQL Server, you do whatever you fee you should. You are the one providing the SLA to your application.